# C# safe way to convert between bytes and other types

Tags: c#

What is the safest way to guarantee that the following operation will be performed correctly:

When I read in 4 bytes as a uint32, I will write it out to a text file.
Later I will open this text file, read the number I wrote out previously, and then convert it back into the 4 bytes for use in other processing.

Comment: Why involve uint32 at all? You'll run into endian issues thinking about it this way if you want your data to be portable. Just write the bytes with Stream.Write and read with Stream.Read.

Comment: I was thinking it would be easier to parse an integer from a text file than parsing 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing this as a string, there isn't a whole lot to this.  Obviously there is no issue converting the number into a string using `.ToString()`.  So the only question I assume is how to go back in a reliable fashion.  The solution is to use `uint.Parse`.  i.e.:

```
var s = "12343632423432";
uint i = uint.Parse(s);
```

(PS: `BitConverter` is not helpful for conversion from strings)

Answer (score 3):

There is the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class to help you convert between primitive types and bytes.

Comment: BitConverter is extremely fast, too, compared to doing masking & shifts in C# code.